# how does cvFindContours work?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, theory

I'm using cvFindContours function in c++ and openCv 2.1, since I have to make a documentation of the function I'm using can someone tell me how this function works, which method for find contours uses and if it possible some theory at the basis of the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation, this function uses the method described in ["Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)"](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=Topological%20structural%20analysis%20of%20digitized%20binary%20images%20by%20border%20following&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).