# What is the algorithm that opencv uses for finding contours?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I need to use `cv::FindContours()` in a program and I have to know the algorithm behind that.

What algorithm does **openCV** use to find contours?

How does it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does cvFindContours work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701248/how-does-cvfindcontours-work)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) it is mentioned this function implements the algorithm of:

> Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized
> Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)

OpenCV is open source if you want to see how this is implemented just need to read the code:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp#L1655

The paper is available [here](https://www.nevis.columbia.edu/%7Evgenty/public/suzuki_et_al.pdf).

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem. I couldn't find this article on the internet(1985!), and also opencv's code is near 1700 lines and owing it is modular, then I can't find the main function that algorithm is used in that function. Can you give me a link or sth that explain the outlook of the algorithm?(Not so complicated, if the simple explanation is also available!)

Comment: mh.. I edited the answer, and added a new link. Please let me know if you need something more.

Comment: @Milad, did that answer your question?

Comment: I haven't read that pdf yet. But as I look through it very quickly I think it's useful for me! But If I have a problem after read it, I will tell you. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone needs a C# implementation I have one :)

Comment: https://theailearner.com/2019/11/19/suzukis-contour-tracing-algorithm-opencv-python/

Comment: Any one has python implementation of the findcontour function

Answer (score 5):

As of Sep. 2018, the paper is available through [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=Topological%20structural%20analysis%20of%20digitized%20binary%20images%20by%20border%20following&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart). Nonetheless, here is the abstract in case the paper is taken down:

> Two border following algorithms are proposed for the topological
>   analysis of digitized binary images. The first one determines the
>   surroundness relations among the borders of a binary image. Since the
>   outer borders and the hole borders have a one-to-one correspondence to
>   the connected components of l-pixels and to the holes, respectively,
>   the proposed algorithm yields a representation of a binary image, from
>   which one can extract some sort of features without reconstructing the
>   image. The second algorithm, which is a modified version of the first,
>   follows only the outermost borders (i.e., the outer borders which are
>   not surrounded by holes). These algorithms can be effectively used in
>   component counting, shrinking, and topological structural analysis of
>   binary images, when a sequential digital computer is used.