# How does findcontours function work. what is the theory behind it

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to get the theory behind the findcontours function. If we take canny edge detection function there are some 5 step to get the final out put. I am trying to search similarly the theory behind this findcontours function.

Comment: Check paper: C-H Teh and Roland T. Chin. On the detection of dominant points on digital curves. Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on, 11(8):859–872, 1989.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the algorithm that opencv uses for finding contours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427474/what-is-the-algorithm-that-opencv-uses-for-finding-contours)

Comment: All are suggesting this paper, but non of the OP has a brief summary of what the paper is and the algorithm is developed in conjunction with the paper