# Manually implement contour detection on an image, without using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am asked to count the number of objects in an image. We are allowed to use the `cv2.dilate` functions, as well as the cv2.thresholding images. The next step would be contouring the images so we can extract the number of objects in the image.

I got it to work using `cv2.findContours`, but I am asked to **not** use this function and instead implement it (or something with similar results) manually.

Current code and output below:

```
    # Read images
    
    img_5 = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)

    # filter on the images to account for the noise.
    
    img_5_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_5, 50, 100, 100)
    
    # Next we are going to apply thresholding to the blurred images, like before
    
    threshold5, thresholded_image5 = cv2.threshold(img_5_blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    # Dilate the images to make the features stand out more, and make them easier to pick up using cv2.findContours. We can 
    # use the same kernel as before.
    
    dilated_image5 = cv2.dilate(thresholded_image5, threshold_kernel, iterations = 5)
    
    # We can proceed by using cv2.findContours (this is what needs to change!)
    
    contours_image5, hierarchy_information5 = cv2.findContours(dilated_image5, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

After this, I get the number of objects in the image by taking `len(contours_image5)`:

```
    print("The number of objects found in the first image is ", len(contours_image5))
    >> 24
```

How do I do the contouring step without using built-in functions? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427474/what-is-the-algorithm-that-opencv-uses-for-finding-contours

Comment: It is easier to implement connected component labeling. There exist some pretty straight-forward algorithms for that.

Comment: print(f"The number of objects found in the first image is  len{contours_image5}")